# How to make code run a certain amount of times before returning something?

Tags: c#, asp.net, function

I made a trivia game and I have to make a method (SuccessOrFail) that will return whether the user beat the trivia or not.

```
namespace D4
{
/// <summary>
/// Displays the trivia and returns whether the user succeeded or not, number of questions asked, and a free piece of trivia.
/// </summary>
public partial class TriviaForm : Form
{
    private Trivia trivia;
    private Question question;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private HashSet<int> pickedQuestion = new HashSet<int>();
    private string usersAnswer;
    private int numCorrectAnswers;
    private int numIncorrectAnswers;

    public TriviaForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.trivia = new Trivia();

        QuestionRandomizer();
        QuestionOutputter();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will return true if succeeded or false if not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Whether the user got the trivia right or not</returns>
    public bool SuccessOrFail(bool wumpus)
    {
        bool successOrFail = false;

        int maxQuestions = 3;
        if (wumpus == true)
            maxQuestions = 5;
        int numNeededCorrect = maxQuestions / 2 + 1;

        if (this.usersAnswer == question.CorrectAnswer.ToString())
            numCorrectAnswers++;
        else
            numIncorrectAnswers++;

        if (numCorrectAnswers + numIncorrectAnswers == maxQuestions)
        {
            if (numCorrectAnswers == numNeededCorrect)
                successOrFail = true;
            else
                successOrFail = false;
            numCorrectAnswers = 0;
            numIncorrectAnswers = 0;

            return successOrFail;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will output a free answer to the player. 
    /// </summary>
    public string FreeTrivia()
    {
        return question.Freetrivia;
    }

    // This method tells the player whether they were correct or not.
    private void CorrectOrNot()
    {
        if (this.usersAnswer == question.CorrectAnswer.ToString())
            MessageBox.Show("Correct");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
    }

    // Displays the questions and answers on the form.
    private void QuestionOutputter()
    {
        this.txtQuestion.Text = question.QuestionText;
        this.txtBox0.Text = question.Answers[0];
        this.txtBox1.Text = question.Answers[1];
        this.txtBox2.Text = question.Answers[2];
        this.txtBox3.Text = question.Answers[3];
    }

    // Clears the TextBoxes and displays a new random question.
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.usersAnswer = txtAnswer.Text;

        CorrectOrNot();
        this.txtQuestion.Clear();
        this.txtBox0.Clear();
        this.txtBox1.Clear();
        this.txtBox2.Clear();
        this.txtBox3.Clear();
        this.txtAnswer.Clear();
        this.txtAnswer.Focus();

        QuestionRandomizer();
        QuestionOutputter();

        this.txtsuc.Text = SuccessOrFail(false).ToString();
    }

    // Choose a random number and assign the corresponding data to question, refreshes the list if all questions used.
    private void QuestionRandomizer()
    {
        if (pickedQuestion.Count < trivia.AllQuestions.Count)
        {
            int random;
            do
            {
                random = rand.Next(trivia.AllQuestions.Count);
            } while (pickedQuestion.Contains(random));

            pickedQuestion.Add(random);

            this.question = trivia.AllQuestions.ToArray()[random];
            if (pickedQuestion.Count == trivia.AllQuestions.ToArray().Length)
                pickedQuestion.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

}

My question is how to make it so that the code asks the user 3 or 5 questions and then returns whether the user won or not?

I was wondering if somehow I could make a public void that would just make the form pop up and ask the user 3 to 5 questions and then once it asks the maximum number of questions, to close and then have a method that returns true if the user won, or false if they didn't. But I literally have no idea how to do that.

Edit: So I know a for loop can make code run more than once. But the problem I'm having is, is that I don't know how to make it so that the trivia game asks 3 to 5 questions BEFORE returning something.

EditAgain: So I've already tried something like what you said (I think), in which I had slightly different code...

```
namespace D4
{
/// <summary>
/// Displays the trivia and returns whether the user succeeded or not, number of questions asked, and a free piece of trivia.
/// </summary>
public partial class TriviaForm : Form
{
    private Trivia trivia;
    private Question question;
            private Map map;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private HashSet<int> pickedQuestion = new HashSet<int>();
    private string usersAnswer;
    private int numCorrectAnswers;
    private int numIncorrectAnswers;
            private bool successOrFail;

    public TriviaForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.trivia = new Trivia();
                    this.map = new Map();

        QuestionRandomizer();
        QuestionOutputter();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will return true if succeeded or false if not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Whether the user got the trivia right or not</returns>
    public bool SuccessOrFail
    {
        get { return this.successOrFail; } }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will output a free answer to the player. 
    /// </summary>
    public string FreeTrivia()
    {
        return question.Freetrivia;
    }

    // This method tells the player whether they were correct or not.
    private void CorrectOrNot()
    {
        if (this.usersAnswer == question.CorrectAnswer.ToString())
            MessageBox.Show("Correct");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
    }

    // Displays the questions and answers on the form.
    private void QuestionOutputter()
    {
        this.txtQuestion.Text = question.QuestionText;
        this.txtBox0.Text = question.Answers[0];
        this.txtBox1.Text = question.Answers[1];
        this.txtBox2.Text = question.Answers[2];
        this.txtBox3.Text = question.Answers[3];
    }

    // Clears the TextBoxes and displays a new random question.
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.usersAnswer = txtAnswer.Text;
                    // The max number of questions that can be asked.
        int maxQuestions = 3;
        if (map.wumpus == true)
            maxQuestions = 5;
                    // The number of questions needed to be answered correctly for the user to win.
        int numNeededCorrect = maxQuestions / 2 + 1;

        if (this.usersAnswer == question.CorrectAnswer.ToString())
            numCorrectAnswers++;
        else
            numIncorrectAnswers++;

        if (numCorrectAnswers + numIncorrectAnswers == maxQuestions)
        {
            if (numCorrectAnswers == numNeededCorrect)
                this.successOrFail = true;
            else
                this.successOrFail = false;
            numCorrectAnswers = 0;
            numIncorrectAnswers = 0;
                            // Somehow close the form.
        }

        CorrectOrNot();
        this.txtQuestion.Clear();
        this.txtBox0.Clear();
        this.txtBox1.Clear();
        this.txtBox2.Clear();
        this.txtBox3.Clear();
        this.txtAnswer.Clear();
        this.txtAnswer.Focus();

        QuestionRandomizer();
        QuestionOutputter();

        this.txtsuc.Text = SuccessOrFail(false).ToString();
    }

    // Choose a random number and assign the corresponding data to question, refreshes the list if all questions used.
    private void QuestionRandomizer()
    {
        if (pickedQuestion.Count < trivia.AllQuestions.Count)
        {
            int random;
            do
            {
                random = rand.Next(trivia.AllQuestions.Count);
            } while (pickedQuestion.Contains(random));

            pickedQuestion.Add(random);

            this.question = trivia.AllQuestions.ToArray()[random];
            if (pickedQuestion.Count == trivia.AllQuestions.ToArray().Length)
                pickedQuestion.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

}

So the main changes in this code are just the new property (SuccessOrFail) which now returns whether the user won or not, by getting the successOrFail variable. This variable is being called in the btnNext_Click where in which I use the amount of correct/incorrect answers to see if they have answered the max number of questions, and if they do and they have the needed amount of correct answers, then the successOrFail variable = true, otherwise, it is false. However when I do this the SuccessOrFail property still returns an initial value of false. Because at the beginning, nothing is set to it.

My question for this code is: Is this better than the before code? Is there some way I can modify this code so that it can only return the SuccessOrFail after all questions have been answered?

Comment: Ususally if you want something to run for a specific number of times, then you use a for-cycle.

Comment: What are you trying to return the result to? You talk about returning something, but you don't specify what receives the result of SuccessOrFail.

Comment: @BG100 Sorry, I thought I mentioned it but I must not have been explaining it too well. What I wanted it to return was a boolean (true if the user won - 2/3 questions or 3/5 questions correct, false if not). Also, what receives it is my group member's code, in which they take the boolean from SuccessOrFail and if it's true the user gets like more arrows, or if false they just lose money.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your question you have a random number of questions asked between 3-5 number of questions. All you need to do is ask a question, once answered return a boolean. If you have the correct number of booleans, return a winning game state.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need a private member variable that keeps track of how many questions have been asked, something like this:

```
private int questionsAsked = 0;
```

Then in your `btnNext_Click` handler, you and increment this total, followed by a check to see if they have answered enough questions to close the form if needed:

```
questionsAsked++;
if (questionsAsked >= 5) this.Hide(); // this will hide the form but keep the object so you can fetch the results after.
```

Then finally, to get the result out of your form, just declare a public property to return a boolean to say if the user won or not. You don't mention what defines a winner so you'll need to add the expression that determines this:

```
public bool IsWinner {

    get {
        return /* true if winner */;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what application framework you have surrounding your form, but you should have a reference to the form object, and can therefore get the result like this:

```
var winner = MyTriviaForm.IsWinner;
```